# Convert SVG with filters to Android Vector Drawable

Tags: android, xml, svg

I need to convert SVG file which contains **filter** tags, which usually consists of fe* tags. (**feFlood**, **feGaussianBlur**,...)
Android Asset Studio and other instruments can not deal with it, and the only thing that came to me was using gradient in vector drawable, but it fits only to **linearGradient** in SVG.
For example, Asset Studio can't convert this code

```
<svg width="230" height="120"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

 <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
 </filter>

 <circle cx="60"  cy="60" r="50" fill="green" />

 <circle cx="170" cy="60" r="50" fill="green"
      filter="url(#blurMe)" />
</svg>
```

Can someone give algo for converting such tags if it is real?